# Ansible playbook takes the wrong "ansible_ssh_private_key_file" from hosts

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a custom 'hosts' script with this output: (part of it)

```
"production-public-web": {
    "hosts": [
        "52.x.y.z"
    ],
    "vars": {
        "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": "/home/ec2-user/.ssh/prod1-frankfurt.pem"
    }
},
"production-internal": {
    "hosts": [
        "172.x.y.z"
    ],
    "vars": {
        "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": "/home/ec2-user/.ssh/prod1-useast.pem"
    }
},
```

The hosts output looks fine and I have a playbook that runs on each server group. **But it seems to mix up the private keys**. Some servers get the right key, some don't. For example (-vvvv):

```
PLAY [production-eu-public-web] *******************

TASK [setup] *********************************************
<52.x.y.z> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<52.x.y.z> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto 
-o     ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
-o 'IdentityFile="/home/ec2-user/.ssh/prod1-useast.pem"'...
```

As you can see, this server took the wrong private key (us-east instead of frankfurt)

I have used different private keys in the past without any issues. Some server DO get the right private key. Regular SSH (with the right key) works.

```
$ ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.0.1.0
```

Running on AWS EC2 (centos)

Any clue?

---

Answer: As [Konstantin Suvorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2795592/konstantin-suvorov) commented - my Hosts script output repeated the same hosts in more than one group. After I eliminated the duplications - it all worked well. Even without the .ssh/config workaround.

Thanks!

Comment: I found a workaround that makes this work - added the private keys paths to the ~/.ssh/config like this: "IdentityFile ~/.ssh/prod1-frankfurt.pem
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/prod1-useast.pem" (with newlines ofc). But the ansible log still shows the same mistakes from before.

Comment: What happens if you drop the "SSH" from the variable? Eg `ansible_private_key_file`?

Comment: Please review your hosts script's output for one host being in multiple groups.
If 52.x.y.z in your example is defined in some other group than production-eu-public-web later in the hosts list it will use it's variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters mixup in the hosts are a result of duplications in the output of the hosts script. Each server should be in exactly one group.